# Error al subir proyecto de Vue a producción

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo una aplicación muy basica con `Vuejs` la cual quiero subir a producción para probarla, ejecute el comando

```
npm run build
```

El cual me creo una carpeta `dist` con un `index.html` y las carpteas `js, css, img`, al subir estos archivos a mi servidor en la consola del navegador me salen los siguiente errores

> app.b77b1ab7.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with
>   a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> app.c83b8068.js:1 Failed to load resource:
>   the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> chunk-vendors.512d43c3.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> /css/carousel.b4d817f1.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> /js/carousel.91739f99.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with 
>   a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> /css/input.72e671f5.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> /css/home.0094a1a4.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded
>   with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> /js/input.05cf4a61.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> /js/home.762faa19.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded
>   with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> app.c83b8068.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> app.b77b1ab7.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with
>   a status of 404 (Not Found)

No entiendo muy bien por que me dice que no encuentra los archivos, no se si fue que olvide configurar algo adicional antes de hacer el `npm run build`.

¿Como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: y en la carpeta que hizo el build se encuentran los archivos?

Comment: estan en sus respectivas carpetas los css en css/.., js en js/..

Comment: probablemente hace el build pero tienes que agregar en tu index.html la carpeta donde va a estar algo como : `<base href="/tu_carpeta" />`

Comment: probablemente estas en nginx/apache2, y lo colocastes en la raiz de la carpeta html , tienes que hacer el paso anterior para que te funcione

Comment: de hecho lo comentado lo dicen [en el foro de Vue](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/router-how-to-set-base-dir-relative-to-index-html-in-app-build/2396)

Comment: por favor puede colocar el package.json creo que hay un error en una dependencia o es que no esta configurado correctamente o realmente no colocaste los permisos a la carpeta. éxito.